# Angular 2 extend a style from styles.scss

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli, angular2-template

In Angular 2, I have a CSS class in my `styles.scss` file:

```
.FirstClass {
}
```

I'm trying to extend this class in a component's .SCSS file (eg.: `MyComponent.scss`) like:

```
.SecondClass {
  @extend .FirstClass;
}
```

I'm getting an error that says `.FirstClass` is not found. Do I assume correctly that class and style in `styles.scss` can be globally referred? Please help me in this.

Comment: No they can't, you have to import them.

Comment: you have to  @import "_styles.scss" into  MyComponent.scss

Comment: Yes you have to use the @import to have the external file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have any file, and you want to use one of its classes in another file, you have to import it first.

**styles.scss**

```
.FirstClass{}
```

**MyComponent.scss**

```
@import 'styles.scss'
.SecondClass{
 @extend .FirstClass;
}
```

SCSS is compile to CSS, hence, if you need to make any changes in the file itself that not related plain css, you have to take it into consideration.

Comment: It is missing a period in `@extend .FirstClass;`.

Comment: @dAxx_ will importing the global scss file into multiple components have an impact on app performance (file size etc.)?