# How to extend a class from an imported SCSS?

Tags: css, angular, sass, extend

shared.scss:

```
.gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

my-component.scss

```
@import url("../../../shared.scss");
.contentWrapper {
   @extend .gridContainer
}
```

When extending to `.gridContainer` from angular component scss(my-component.scss) I'm getting this error. The import is fine here.
Is it possible to extend like this? If not how to access the class or variable from the shared.scss?

> ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: **The target selector was not found.**
> Use `@extend .gridContainer !optional` to avoid this error.`

Comment: for some reason, it seems that shared.scss is not imported properly, can you double check the path? also try @import "../../../shared.scss";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the import statement is correct. Try `@import 'shared.scss'`

Similar issue to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480665/271012